# Separating old 2 x 4 brick with wheel holder

Tags: cleaning, disassembly

I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to separate the clear bottom piece from the brick on part# 7049b "Brick, Modified 2 x 4 with Wheels Holder Old and Trans-Clear Bottom" without breaking anything.  Photo for reference:

[image]

I have one that has a loose bottom and it got me wondering if they could be separated without breaking them. Some of the ones I have are kinda nasty inside, while others have loose tubes that don't retain the axles very well anymore.  It would be nice if I could take them apart for cleaning and repairs, but most of them seemed "glued" together very well.  I realize they aren't meant to be taken apart, but wondered if some process including heat or something would work.  Has anyone ever tried this?  If so could you please share you experience?

Comment: Here's a [patent drawing](http://brickfetish.com/patents/us/us_3234683_1.html) showing the inner workings of the brick...

Comment: @Uli - That is very interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually have one of these that comes apart easily (no idea where the internal tubes are).

[image]

It appears that the glue that used to hold them together gave out. You can still see where it used to be, around the edges of the clear piece, and at the tips of the 4 prongs on the clear piece.

[image]

[image]

If I were going to try to take one apart, I would probably try cutting the glue around the edge with a razor blade, and hope that the glue further in isn't strong enough to prevent pushing it out with a paperclip of something thought the axle holes.

Comment: As I hoped, this gives us a lot of information on the internal working of how they were "glued" together.  Thank you for posting these pictures!

Comment: This was, in all reality, the most useful information given.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the experience.

- My process:

  01 -  <strike>Boil water for 7mins.</strike> Bring water to a boil. ** *EDIT by* *[Kat](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/8362/kat)*.

  02 - Toss *LEGO* in.

  03 - Simmer for five minutes.

  04 - With some tools find an edge, and pry.

  05 - If piece cools down repeat steps 02-04...

The final analysis?

We'll let your words speak the truth:

> "...seemed "glued" together very well. I realize they aren't meant to
>   be taken apart..." - *JohnnyB*.

[image]

Even though the attempt was a failure, it did confirm [*Uli's* upload of the piece schematics.](http://brickfetish.com/patents/us/us_3234683_1.html)

Added some light blue coloring to *Uli's* pic to help distinguish exactly what we're looking at.

Schematic Figures 4,5,6 and 7 is/are the transparent clear piece.

Looking again at "Fig.7",  note how both that transparent and black outer shell interlock and merge together.

Finally, imaging glue in between the two, which explains why we had trouble with disassembly.

[image]

Comment: Think it'll buff out? :0  It died for science, a sacrifice in hopes that no others will share it's fate.  Your efforts and blatant disregard for that brick's well being are appreciated!

Comment: @JohnnyB So the answer just **boiled down** to "impossible"... : )

Comment: Why "boil water for seven minutes"? Do you mean bring water to a boil or did you actually boil just water for seven minutes?

Comment: By the amount of damage done to get it apart I doubt that the clear part was glued in it looks more like it was an ultrasonic weld.

Comment: @Kat he just wanted to make it safe for drinking. It's called Multitasking. I kid, of course.

Comment: I actually have at-least one of these which comes apart very easily. Perhaps it wasn't glued properly.

Comment: @ Alexander O'Mara - Pictures please!  Would love to see the insides of both pieces in their un-mangled form.